# How to draw lines or shapes on an AVFrame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanna draw video overlays like lines, circles, rectangles and print texts on an AVFrame by using the ffmpeg's functions, not command line utility.

Is there any one knows how to do it?

Do you have the source code for this function?

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question when I started to work on video streaming issues.
Since an AVFrame is a decoded video data, adding overlays on video data means transcoding it. I add overlays while rendering. I used SDL library to render AvFrames and add overlays.